# Open a favorite web page quickly using the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, firefox, web-browsing, shortcut

I have a Google spreadsheet that I open every morning

I'd like to open it quickly using just the keyboard after startup, as opposed to:

- opening Firefox
- going to the address bar
- typing in the tag name
- arrowing down
- hitting enter

Is there a way to do this with just a few keystrokes?

Assuming I don't already have a browser running (I prefer to use Firefox if that matters)

Also, I would rather not have to use a third party app to do this

**UPDATE:**

Realize that I could have FF run at startup which would save me at least one step...

**SUMMARY:**

I would really like to have an experience like opening the web page from Spotlight if possible; the webloc file does show up in spotlight but it's way down the list... I'd like the first few letters to bring it to the top. Perhaps there is a way to assign priority to Spotlight items?

Comment: Safari maps `Command` + the number keys to the first 10 bookmark bar items

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm hoping to stick with Firefox and would also like to do this without already having a browser running (edited question for better clarity)

Comment: You can assign priority of spotlight file types in the spotlight preferences

Comment: Thanks, so far this isn't helping move the result up the list, see my comment on **samh**'s answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create shortcut to Your page somewhere on Your hard drive (drag and drop address from Your browser). Then use **BetterTouchTool** http://www.boastr.de to launch this link using global keyboard shortcut.

[image]

You can also drag this `webloc` file to **Dock**.

Edit: you can also add this `webloc` file to `LoginItems` and Your webpage will start automatically when You log in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I noticed that I could drag it to the dock (not a bad option); would rather stay away from 3rd party apps as mentioned though

Comment: So You need to use keyboard instead of clicking this with mouse/trackpad ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Spotlight to do this, in System Preferences > Spotlight you can drag and drop "Web Pages" to the top of list.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but the result is still way down the list. What constitutes a "web page", I have the webloc file saved on my desktop currently for testing... Thanks :)

Comment: Hm. It turns out "web pages" are pages in Safari's history. .webloc files show up for me in Spotlight's "other" section. Your other option within Firefox would be to press Command-L and start typing. If it's saved as a bookmark in Firefox, it should appear at or near the top of the list as you type the first view characters.

Answer (score 0):

I use [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) and it can do what you want. Assuming you have added the spreadsheet to your firefox favorites, You would just:

1. Hit <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>
2. Begin typing the title of the page
3. Hit <kbd>return</kbd> once the correct favorite appears

LaunchBar does cost and though I think it is worth the cost, there are two alternatives that are free and almost certainly will work for you: [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) or [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com)

Comment: Thanks, I don't really want to get a whole new app just to access one web page quickly, unless it's really worthwhile to use the app for other purposes that I haven't discovered a need for yet.

Comment: All three apps are useful for quickly accessing lots of different things. I barely scratch the surface of launch bar's capabilities, but I like it for launching apps, keeping a clipboard history, and jumping quickly to websites or songs that I want to listen to.